# How to pass <f:attribute> even parent rendered="false"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl, render, jsf-2.2

- I have a nested `<f:attribute>` in a `<p:column>`.
- The `<p:column>` is rendered dynamically from a `<f:foreach>` which means the `<f:attribute >` will not be taken in consideration if `<p:column rendered="false">`.

I want to pass `<f:attribute>` even if (`parent`) column is `not rendered`, is there a way to **over-pass/skip** the `rendered` **test** somehow ?

**This is needed to save changes made on columns(reordering,resize, show/hide)

Code snippet :

```
<c:forEach items="#{datatableBean.table}"
           var="column" 
           varStatus="loop">

  ////Column 0////////////

  <p:column headerText="#{column.userListname}"
            width="#{column.width}"
            resizable="#{column.resizable}"
            rendered="#{column.dbname=='studyUid' and column.visible}">
  <!--here if parent is not rendered i wont be able to get the changes made on
  this column from backing bean in order to persist the changes on db. -->
     <f:attribute name="myCol" 
                  value="#{column}"/>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{exam.studyUid}"
                    styleClass="fonty"/>
  </p:column>

 ////Column n////////////

</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please state the concrete problem you're currently facing for which you thought that whatever you stated in the question is causing it. The `rendered` attribtue has namely totally no influence on how `<c:forEach>` and `<f:attribute>` behave as they run during view build time already, not during view render time.

Comment: The question is why do you want to pass any argument to something that should not be visible. And it would be better to use ui:repeat instead of c:forEach.